# sending welcome mail to users after granting access

Tags: 2010, powershell

In Sharepoint 2010, is it possible to trigger the standard "x.y. has granted you access to..." email with powershell? (or any other way) 
I am looping trough a list that contains authorization requests to process, and I would like to send out the same mail that the users receive when I grant the access manually.

Comment: are you looping through using powershell.?

Comment: yes, there is a list that contains a queue of pre-defined actions, and one of them is grant access to users to a given url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, I dont think you could get the same mail using powershell, instead once after granting access, you can use the below piece of code and send email to the users. For that, once after granting access using powershell, pass on the user information to the below code,

```
$Username = "MyUserName";
$Password= "MyPassword";

function Send-ToEmail([string]$email){

    $message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage;
    $message.From = "YourName@gmail.com";
    $message.To.Add($email);
    $message.Subject = "subject text here...";
    $message.Body = "body text here...";


    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", "587");
    $smtp.EnableSSL = $true;
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
    $smtp.send($message);
    write-host "Mail Sent" ; 
 }
Send-ToEmail  -email "reciever@gmail.com";
```

Comment: Well, no is also an answer :( I was hoping that this exists somewhere within the SharePoint object model